# Unable to run parallel tests in Cucumber &Testng

Tags: java, cucumber, testng, parallel-testing

I am trying to run parallel tests in 2 browsers using, Testng and cucumber.

Getting the below exception ,

> cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: When a hook declares an argument
>   it must be of type cucumber.api.Scenario. public void
>   com.sample.data_republic.sample_ebay.EbayTest.loadBrowser(java.lang.String)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:52)
>     at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:224)

Code sample given below.

```
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

public class EbayTest extends EbayPageObjects {

    public WebDriver driver;
    Properties propertyObj;

    @Before
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void loadBrowser(String browser) {
        // If the browser is Firefox, then do this
        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/geckodriver");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }

        propertyObj = readPropertyFile();
        driver.get(propertyObj.getProperty("url"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Before hook` is a cucumber method, not a testNg method, which is injected only with the `Scenario` object. So cannot use the `@Parameters` annotation on it to pass parameter values. You need to use before hook like below.

```
@Before
public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario) {
```

or without the scenario object

```
 @Before
    public void beforeScenario() {
```

Either you can store the browser value in a properties file and access it in before hook. Or instantiate the driver in the BeforeClass or BeforeMethod of testNg in the runner class where you can use the parameters annotation.

```
@BeforeClass
@Parameters("browser")
public void loadBrowser(String browser) {
```